# How to get the Second Value of Select Option Tag

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML as shown

```
<select class="m-wrap" id="T1Select" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
   <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select T1</option>
   <option value="Ice Creams">Ice Creams</option>
   <option value="Popcorn">Popcorn</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get the Second Value as shown

```
var aa = $("#T1Select option[value='2']").text();
alert(aa);
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zyrndtLb/

Could anybody please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `eq()` to grab the index of any element.

So your example would look like this:

```
var aa = $("#T1Select option").eq(1).text();
alert(aa); // Alerts "Ice Creams"
```

The above code snippet will alert "Ice Creams", which is the "second element" in the zero-indexed list of options. If you are wanting to target the 'Popcorn' element, simply add one to the `eq()` index. like this:

```
var bb = $("#T1Select option").eq(2).text(); 
alert(bb); // Alerts "Popcorn"
```

**[Here is your updated fiddle with the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/zyrndtLb/3/)**: http://jsfiddle.net/zyrndtLb/3/

**Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child`:

```
var aa = $("#T1Select option:nth-child(2)").text();
```

You can't target it with `value`, because the `value` of the 2nd option is `Ice Creams`, not `2`.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of use case Jquery provide the `:nth-child() Selector` [doc](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) or `.eq()` [doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
var aa = $("#T1Select option:nth-child(2)").text();
alert(aa);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="m-wrap" id="T1Select" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
   <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select T1</option>
   <option value="Ice Creams">Ice Creams</option>
   <option value="Popcorn">Popcorn</option>
</select>
```